# How do I make my discord python bot recognize response in chat after command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So in short. I want to made a regular command that makes the bot ask a question and gives an a,b,c answer. I want to make it look for the next message of the person that triggered the command and check the message and see if it's the correct answer.

So I am guessing I have to use the code:

```
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
```

Do I compare the person who sent the message to the person the bot is expecting to answer and if so, where would I be best off storing that info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guessed wrong, you should use the `bot.wait_for` method, example

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author

    await ctx.send("whatever")
    message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send(f"Thanks for the reply! Your message: {message.content}")
```

#### Reference:

- [`Bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)